# Django Cookiecutter Production Server Setup on DigitalOcean

Tags: django, cookiecutter-django

I am trying to setup my Django Cookiecutter code on an Ubuntu server hosted on Digital Ocean.  (My first attempt at such a thing.)

It does not appear that my .env file is loading?

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://myapp:pwd123@127.0.0.1:5432/myapp
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=187.99.73.187,myapp.com,187.99.73.187:8000
DJANGO_ADMIN_URL=admin
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.production
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=A8fpfkN5}...m5~^jggSo3wq`0Z*
```

I am using the latest version of Cookiecutter. https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django

Do I have to do something special to activate/recognize this code?

Right now I am getting an error of add '187.99.73.187' to ALLOWED_HOSTS. But it is in the env file.

I also had Postgres error based on not getting data from this new .env file.

I see instructions and videos for setting up Cookiecutter on Docker, Heroku and PythonAnywhere.  Just not for a simple Linux installation.

Thanks.

Comment: I have not worked on digital ocean(so can't suggest how), but have you set server environment's `DJANGO_READ_DOT_ENV_FILE` value to `True`. Else it will not read the `.env` file in project root

Comment: ok, let me check. I was just about to give up and resort to Upwork. Thanks!

Comment: DO is just Ubuntu. Also having issues with the gunicorn because the WSGI file is moved.  a much higher degree of difficulty than I expected.